# Python/Matplotlib - How to plot a vector sum on top of a circular histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, histogram

I am trying to plot both a circular histogram and a vector (overlapping) on the same polar plot, but cannot get the vector to show up.

Basically, my data set consists of the times at which unitary events occur during a repeating cycle. This data is in the array "all_phases",  which is just a list of degree values for each of these events. I want to show (1) the overall distribution of events w/ a circular histogram (bins corresponding to degree ranges) and (2) a vector sum as a measure of the coherence of all of these values (treating each event as a unit vector).

I can plot either one of these things individually on the subplot titled "histo", but when I try to plot both, only the histogram shows up. I have tried playing with the z-indexes of both objects to no use. The code is:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import math

array = np.array

all_phases = [array([-38.24240218]), array([-120.51570738]), array([-23.70224663]), 
array([114.9540152]), array([ 2.94523445]), array([-2.16112692]), array([-18.72274284]),
array([13.2292216]), array([-95.5659992]), array([15.69046269]), array([ 51.12022047]), 
array([-89.10567276]), array([ 41.77283949]), array([-9.92584921]), array([-7.59680678]), 
array([166.71824996]), array([-178.94642752]), array([-23.75819463]), array([38.69481261]), 
array([-52.26651244]), array([-57.40976514]), array([33.68226762]), array([-122.1818295]), 
array([ 10.17007425]), array([-38.03726335]),array([44.9504975]), array([ 134.63972923]), 
array([ 63.02516932]),array([-106.54049292]), array([-25.6527599])]

number_bins = 60
bin_size = 360/number_bins
cluster_num = 1

counts, theta = np.histogram(all_phases, np.arange(-180, 180 + bin_size, bin_size), density=True)
theta = theta[:-1]+ bin_size/2.
theta = theta * np.pi / 180
a_deg = map(lambda x: np.ndarray.item(x), all_phases)
a_rad = map(lambda x: math.radians(x), a_deg)

a_cos = map(lambda x: math.cos(x), a_rad)
a_sin = map(lambda x: math.sin(x), a_rad)

uv_x = sum(a_cos)/len(a_cos)
uv_y = sum(a_sin)/len(a_sin)
uv_radius = np.sqrt((uv_x*uv_x) + (uv_y*uv_y))
uv_phase = np.angle(complex(uv_x, uv_y))
"""
plot histogram and vector sum
"""
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.16, 0.05, 0.56])

histo = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
histo.yaxis.set_ticks(())
histo.arrow(0,0,0.11, 1, head_width=.01, zorder=2)
plt.suptitle("Phase distribution for Neuron #" + str(cluster_num), fontsize=15, y=.94)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.12, right=0.95, top=0.78, wspace=0.4)
width = (2*np.pi) / number_bins
bars = histo.bar(theta, counts, width = width, bottom=0.002)

for r, bar in zip(counts, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.jet(r / max(counts)))
    bar.set_alpha(0.7)
    bar.set_zorder(1)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin (counts.min())*len(all_phases)*bin_size, vmax=(counts.max())*len(all_phases)*bin_size)
cb1 = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
                orientation='vertical', norm=norm, alpha=0.4,
                ticks=np.arange(0, (counts.max())*len(all_phases)*bin_size)+1, )
cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=9)
cb1.solids.set_rasterized(True)
cb1.set_label("# spikes")
cb1.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')

plt.show()
cluster_num = cluster_num + 1
```

vs_radius and vs_phase are the parameters for the vector sum arrow I want to put on the polar plot, which I end up calling w/ histo.arrow().

My suspicion is that it might have something to do with trying to put two things on a subplot object?

Any help or thoughts would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: You should create a [mcve] such that everyone can reproduce the issue. Without a minimal example it's really hard to identify the problem.

Comment: Hi - it's fixed now!! you should be able to just copy and past the gray section, run it, and see what I'm seeing. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Are you seeing a bunch of errors when you run this code? Because I sure am.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: It's Python 2.7 - not sure if it'll work with 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `FancyArrow` that is used by `Axes.arrow()` does not play well with polar plots.
Instead, you could use the `annotate()` function to draw a simple arrow that works better in the case of polar plots.

for example:

```
# Compute pie slices
N = 20
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
radii = 10 * np.random.rand(N)
width = np.pi / 4 * np.random.rand(N)

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)

# Use custom colors and opacity
for r, bar in zip(radii, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.viridis(r / 10.))
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)


v_angle = 0.275*np.pi
v_length = 4

ax.annotate('',xy=(v_angle, v_length), xytext=(v_angle,0), xycoords='data', arrowprops=dict(width=5, color='red'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

As a general rule, when you deal with polar plot, you have to work just as if you were working with a linear plot. That is to say, you shouldn't try to draw your arrow from `(0,0)` but rather from `(uv_phase, 0)`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)
# Use custom colors and opacity
for r, bar in zip(radii, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.viridis(r / 10.))
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)

ax.annotate('',xy=(v_angle, v_length), xytext=(v_angle,0), xycoords='data', arrowprops=dict(width=5, color='red'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this worked.

It turns out there were two reasons it wasn't working (one of which was switching from the FancyArrow to annotate as you suggested). Secondly, the vector sum wasn't normalized to the 'tallest' histogram bin - so I was trying to plot a vector sum that was several orders of magnitude larger than the histogram itself. By multiplying the vector sum by 'max(counts)' i.e. the largest bin, it normalized the data and returned a vector that fit on the histogram.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you think my solution answered your question, consider accepting it by clicking on the green arrow next to it.